# Prove this formula for $\cos{n\theta}-\cos{n\alpha}$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $n$ be any positive integer, prove that $$\cos{n\theta}-\cos{n\alpha}=2^{n-1}[\cos \theta - \cos \alpha]\left[\cos \theta -\cos \left(\alpha + \frac {2\pi}n\right)\right]\cdots\left[\cos \theta -\cos \left(\alpha + (n-1)\frac {2\pi}n\right)\right]$$

I am struggling to establish this result. I have tried induction, but it doesn't help. Could I have a hint?

Comment: Have you tried using $\cos(x) = \dfrac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}2$ ?

Comment: Try using the De Moivre's theorem along with binomial theorem

Comment: Yep, I have tried writing in terms of exponentials.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos nx=T_n(\cos x)$ where $T_n$ is a *Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind*. This is a polynomial of degree $n$ with leading coefficient $1/2^{n-1}$. Your identity amounts to
$$T_n(u)-\cos ny=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(u
-\cos\left(y+\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\right).$$
To prove this, one needs to prove that the zeroes of the polynomial $T_n(u)-\cos ny$ are the $\cos(y+2\pi k/n)$,